# Routing error on custom resource action using "member do"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is in my routes.rb file:

```
resources :orders do
  member do
    get 'confirm'
    get 'cancel'
  end
end
```

Of course I wrote the 'confirm' and 'cancel' actions in my orders_controller.rb:

```
def confirm
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  #...
end

def cancel
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  #...
end
```

..and created both "confirm.html.erb" and "cancel.html.erb" files in my "app/views/orders/" folder.

But when I try to access **confirm_order_url** or **cancel_order_url** I am always running into this routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"confirm", :controller=>"orders"}
```

Can't figure out what's missing!
Any idea please?

PS: I'm using RoR v.3.1.0

**EDIT#1:**
It seems the routes are set properly:

```
$ rake routes
[..]
 confirm_order GET    /orders/:id/confirm(.:format) {:action=>"confirm", :controller=>"orders"}
  cancel_order GET    /orders/:id/cancel(.:format)  {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"orders"}
        orders GET    /orders(.:format)             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"orders"}
               POST   /orders(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"orders"}
     new_order GET    /orders/new(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"orders"}
    edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"orders"}
         order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orders"}
               PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"orders"}
               DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"orders"}
[...]
```

**EDIT#2:**
Maybe when I call confirm_order_url Rails doesn't know how to generate the route which should be like "orders/:id/confirm" because @order.id hasn't been assigned yet.
But I am calling this method after @order.save.
Namely, here:

```
  if @order.save
  response = PAYPAL_EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(@order.price_in_cents,
  :ip                => @order.ip_address,
  :return_url        => confirm_order_url,
  :cancel_return_url => cancel_order_url 
  )
  redirect_to PAYPAL_EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
```

So this leads to a subquestion: is @order.id set after the call to @order.save?
And if not, how can I set it properly before calling an helper method such ad confirmation_order_url?

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to Jayendra Patil i fixed my code this way:

```
  if @order.save
  response = PAYPAL_EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(@order.price_in_cents,
  :ip                => @order.ip_address,
  :return_url        => confirm_order_url(@order),
  :cancel_return_url => cancel_order_url(@order) 
  )
  redirect_to PAYPAL_EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
```

I was wrongly assuming that Rails could guess for which @order I was calling a "member" url, so the answer is to pass @order as the argument for member routes. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the contents of `rake routes`

Comment: I did it on your suggestion under "EDIT#1", ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generates routes as -

```
confirm_order GET    /orders/:id/confirm(.:format) {:action=>"confirm", :controller=>"orders"}
cancel_order GET    /orders/:id/cancel(.:format)  {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"orders"}
```

you should use the order object or id with these routes -

```
confirm_order_url(:id => @order.id)
confirm_order_url(@order)
```

Also Rails automatically assigns the id to the instance after it is saved so @order.id should work.

Comment: Damn! Of course! Thank you. I'm editing the question now to show how I fixed it...